# animate scroll on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've managed to get the scroll working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ez6q6row/):

but on my website it fails to work properly. Any ideas why? It's essentially the same thing. Apologies since it's really long, I'm just not sure where exactly the problem is

html:

```
<body> 

        <div class='container'>

    <nav class='sidebar'>
        <ul>
            <li class='main'>
            <a href='#'>0</a>   
            </li>
            <li class='subset' id='first-element'>
            <a href='#'>1</a>

            </li>
            <li class='subset' id='second-element'>
            <a href='#'>2</a>   
            </li>
            <li class='subset' id='third-element'>
            <a href='#'>3</a>
            </li>
                    </ul>
    </nav>

        <div class='window-top' id='window-top'>

        <div class='section' id='first'>1</div>

        <div class='section' id='second'>2</div>
        <div class='section' id='third'>3</div>
        </div>                          

        <div class='window'>

        </div>


        </div>





    <script src='js/script.js'></script>
    <script src='js/classie.js'></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   


</body>
```

JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#first-element').on('click', function(){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#third').offset().top
        }, 500);
    });

    });
```

some relevant (?) css:

```
.window-top{
left:25%;
float:right;
width:75%;
background-image: url('../pic/bg.png');
height:80%;
}
.section
{
height:100%;
min-width:100%;
}

#second{
background-color:blue;
}

#third{
background-color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call your scripts after jQuery:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   
<script src='js/script.js'></script>
<script src='js/classie.js'></script>
```

Or

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#first-element').on('click', function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#third').offset().top
    }, 500);
});

});
```

jQuery needs to be loaded before it can be used.

Comment: thank you. I think i'm going to go and cry quietly in a corner now.